# How can I use Bootstrap Multiselect Dropdown in AngularJS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I want to use Bootstrap Multiselect Dropdown http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/ in AngularJS. I hear that it's necessary to move it to Directive. But I think it's quite complicated & don't know what I have to do. If you have experienced, please guide me! Tks.

Comment: Do you need to use the bootstrap multi-select, or can you use select2? http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ This has already been wrapped as Angular directive: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2

Comment: ui-select2 has now been deprecated. Use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't need to create code that's very re-usable, it's actually not that complicated. The first step is to create a basic directive and to get the DOM element:

```js
angular.module('yourapp', [])

.directive('multiselectDropdown', [function() {
    return function(scope, element, attributes) {

        element = $(element[0]); // Get the element as a jQuery element

        // Below setup the dropdown:

        element.multiselect({
            option1: 123,
            option2: "abcd",
            // etc.
        })

        // Below maybe some additional setup
    }
}]);
```

Basically, once you are within the directive, it's actually just regular jQuery or JS code.

Then in your HTML code:

```html
<select multiselectDropdown >
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">One</option>
    <option value="3">One</option>
</select>
```

You can also specify additional attributes on the DIV and get the values using the `attributes` parameter of the directive.

Comment: Just as an addon this is an excellent model for all jquery plugins you want to migrate to AngularJS. Shouldn't your 'multiselectDropdown' be 'multiselect-dropdown'?

Comment: Actually, the latest version of AngularJS supports many way to assign directives in HTML, I think `multiselect-dropdown`, `multiselectdropdown`, `data-multiselect-dropdown`, `class="multiselect-dropdown"` (and probably more) are all valid. "multiselect-dropdown" might indeed be more proper HTML than "multiselectDropdown".

Comment: @Laurent Sorry, but I haven't really known what to do next :|

Comment: @OcChuojDau, well for a start, does the code make sense at all? :) If it doesn't, what is it you don't understand?

Comment: @Laurent To me, Directive is being a very difficult & big aspect :| Could you please help me to write the code in more details in this situation? I really appreciate!

Comment: @OcChuojDau, actually the code above is pretty much all of it, all you need to do now is setup the options in `element.multiselect()`. If there's something not working for you, you need to be more specific about what it is.

Comment: @Laurent I haven't understood which type of options put into element.multiselect(). Could u pls tell me a little more detailed?

Comment: @OcChuojDau, just try with no options for a start, then add the options you need based on the page you linked - http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Comment: @Laurent Please check for me. My ng-repeat set in <select multiselect-dropdown>...</select> is not displayed :( http://plnkr.co/edit/NGQZmW?p=preview

Answer (score 16):

Here is a directive I use in my project. It works on Chrome and Firefox. You can change the options based on your own need.

```
angular.module('yourApp')
.directive('yourDirective', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.multiselect({
                buttonClass: 'btn',
                buttonWidth: 'auto',
                buttonContainer: '<div class="btn-group" />',
                maxHeight: false,
                buttonText: function(options) {
                    if (options.length == 0) {
                      return 'None selected <b class="caret"></b>';
                    }
                    else if (options.length > 3) {
                      return options.length + ' selected  <b class="caret"></b>';
                    }
                    else {
                      var selected = '';
                      options.each(function() {
                        selected += $(this).text() + ', ';
                      });
                      return selected.substr(0, selected.length -2) + ' <b class="caret"></b>';
                    }
                }
            });

            // Watch for any changes to the length of our select element
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return element[0].length;
            }, function () {
                element.multiselect('rebuild');
            });

            // Watch for any changes from outside the directive and refresh
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
                element.multiselect('refresh');
            });

        }

    };
});
```

Update two snippets for the directive which working on AngularJS v1.3.15 and bootstrap-multiselect v0.9.6: [JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/ethanph5/6554975), [CoffeeScript](https://gist.github.com/ethanph5/384cea2e50ef46962c49)

Comment: this works great for me EXCEPT on firefox. When the buttonText function is called after I select something in firefox, the length is always zero, so it doesnt update the text shown. Thoughts?

Comment: @LukeOllett It works in my project on both Chrome and Firefox. I guess there might be some issues in the HTML file. In select tag, I use `ng-options` and allow `multiple`.

Comment: mine looks like this ... <select ng-if="event.guests.length" class="multiselect"
            ng-options="guest.id as (guest.name | truncate:40) for guest in event.guests"
            data-placeholder="No Guests Selected"
            ng-model="guestSelection"
            multiple="multiple"
            table="table"
            multiselect-table-dropdown>
  </select>

Comment: looks like the repo was updated recently with a similar bug fix and my problem has been resolved. thanks for following up and this solution.

Comment: @LukeOllett I reached the similar situation before. That snippet works perfectly and suddenly fails for no reason. It turned out some updated changes cause the problem.

Comment: hi! is it possible to use this directive in combination with the ui-bootstrap directives? the dropdown directive seems not work or to compile. any ideas ?

Comment: @MrMuh Actually, I don't know. I use ui-bootstrap in my project too. But I don't use the drop-down directive with this one together. I think you don't need the drop-down directive to create a drop-down list if you are using Bootstrap Multiselect Dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on Ethan Wu's answer. I fixed a couple of bugs and added options that are overridable on the element: `<select multi-select includeSelectAllOption="true" enableFiltering="true" enableClickableOptGroups="true" enableCollapsibleOptGroups="true" multiple ng-model="vm.selectedPlants" ng-options="plant.name group by plant.operatingCompanyName for plant in vm.plants"></select>`

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/homer2/9df015bf110d0c3f36ae5ce752580580)

```
// AngularJS: 1.5.8
// bootstrap-multiselect: 0.9.13

angular.module('SocoApp')
    .directive('multiSelect', function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs: any) {

                var options: any = {
                    onChange: function (optionElement, checked) {
                        if (optionElement != null) {
                            $(optionElement).removeProp('selected');
                        }
                        if (checked) {
                            $(optionElement).prop('selected', 'selected');
                        }
                        element.change();
                    }
                };

                //attrs are lowercased by Angular, but options must match casing of bootstrap-multiselect
                if (attrs.enablehtml) options.enableHTML = JSON.parse(attrs.enablehtml); //default:  false
                if (attrs.buttonclass) options.buttonClass = attrs.buttonclass; //default:  'btn btn-default'
                if (attrs.inheritclass) options.inheritClass = JSON.parse(attrs.inheritclass); //default:  false
                if (attrs.buttonwidth) options.buttonWidth = attrs.buttonwidth; //default:  'auto'
                if (attrs.buttoncontainer) options.buttonContainer = attrs.buttoncontainer; //default:  '<div class="btn-group" />'
                if (attrs.dropright) options.dropRight = JSON.parse(attrs.dropright); //default:  false
                if (attrs.dropup) options.dropUp = JSON.parse(attrs.dropup); //default:  false
                if (attrs.selectedclass) options.selectedClass = attrs.selectedclass; //default:  'active'
                if (attrs.maxheight) options.maxHeight = attrs.maxheight; //default:  false,  // Maximum height of the dropdown menu. If maximum height is exceeded a scrollbar will be displayed.
                if (attrs.includeselectalloption) options.includeSelectAllOption = JSON.parse(attrs.includeselectalloption); //default:  false
                if (attrs.includeselectallifmorethan) options.includeSelectAllIfMoreThan = attrs.includeselectallifmorethan; //default:  0
                if (attrs.selectalltext) options.selectAllText = attrs.selectalltext; //default:  ' Select all'
                if (attrs.selectallvalue) options.selectAllValue = attrs.selectallvalue; //default:  'multiselect-all'
                if (attrs.selectallname) options.selectAllName = JSON.parse(attrs.selectallname); //default:  false
                if (attrs.selectallnumber) options.selectAllNumber = JSON.parse(attrs.selectallnumber); //default:  true
                if (attrs.selectalljustvisible) options.selectAllJustVisible = JSON.parse(attrs.selectalljustvisible); //default:  true
                if (attrs.enablefiltering) options.enableFiltering = JSON.parse(attrs.enablefiltering); //default:  false
                if (attrs.enablecaseinsensitivefiltering) options.enablecaseinsensitivefiltering = JSON.parse(attrs.enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering); //default:  false
                if (attrs.enablefullvaluefiltering) options.enableFullValueFiltering = JSON.parse(attrs.enablefullvaluefiltering); //default:  false
                if (attrs.enableclickableoptgroups) options.enableClickableOptGroups = JSON.parse(attrs.enableclickableoptgroups); //default:  false
                if (attrs.enablecollapsibleoptgroups) options.enableCollapsibleOptGroups = JSON.parse(attrs.enablecollapsibleoptgroups); //default:  false
                if (attrs.filterplaceholder) options.filterPlaceholder = attrs.filterplaceholder; //default:  'Search'
                if (attrs.filterbehavior) options.filterBehavior = attrs.filterbehavior; //default:  'text', // possible options: 'text', 'value', 'both'
                if (attrs.includefilterclearbtn) options.includeFilterClearBtn = JSON.parse(attrs.includefilterclearbtn); //default:  true
                if (attrs.preventinputchangeevent) options.preventInputChangeEvent = JSON.parse(attrs.preventinputchangeevent); //default:  false
                if (attrs.nonselectedtext) options.nonSelectedText = attrs.nonselectedtext; //default:  'None selected'
                if (attrs.nselectedtext) options.nSelectedText = attrs.nselectedtext; //default:  'selected'
                if (attrs.allselectedtext) options.allSelectedText = attrs.allselectedtext; //default:  'All selected'
                if (attrs.numberdisplayed) options.numberDisplayed = attrs.numberdisplayed; //default:  3
                if (attrs.disableifempty) options.disableIfEmpty = JSON.parse(attrs.disableifempty); //default:  false
                if (attrs.disabledtext) options.disabledText = attrs.disabledtext; //default:  ''
                if (attrs.delimitertext) options.delimiterText = attrs.delimitertext; //default:  ', '

                element.multiselect(options);

                // Watch for any changes to the length of our select element
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    //debugger;
                    return element[0].length;
                }, function () {
                    scope.$applyAsync(element.multiselect('rebuild'));
                });

                // Watch for any changes from outside the directive and refresh
                scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
                    element.multiselect('refresh');
                });
            }
        };
    });
```