# AngularJS directive for a multi-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select, directive

I am having trouble populating my multi-select.  I am using this version of the multi-select  http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

I have looked at this stack overflow page ([How can I use Bootstrap Multiselect Dropdown in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954605/how-can-i-use-bootstrap-multiselect-dropdown-in-angularjs)) but I am still having problems.  I am trying to populate my multi-select with data that I grab from a database which gets stored in provData.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <select class="form-control" multiple ht-multi-select ng-model="patient.provid" ng-options="prov.id as prov.code for prov in provData">
        <option value="{{prov.id}}">{{prov.code}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is my directive:

```
templates.directive('htMultiSelect', function() {
return {
  replace: true,
  require: 'ngModel',
  scope: {},
  link:function(scope, element, attrs) {
    console.log($(element));
    console.log('hit');
      // Below setup the dropdown:

      $(element).multiselect({
        enableClickableOptGroups: true
      });

      // Below maybe some additional setup
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
       $(element).multiselect('refresh');
      });
  }
};
});
```

My main issue is I can not populate my multi-select with data from provData and I can not get it to set the ng-model.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can u create a plunker with your example?

Comment: what is the point of the directive? also, the model is going to be the object from the array, not the id of that object. http://plnkr.co/edit/CPhENXYXP7csvW00up2I?p=preview

Comment: @jw56578 I guess what I want is a select box that has checkboxes in it.  The select box needs to be dynamics so I can't just hardcode in some providers.  So if I can get a select box that has checkboxes in it that all saves to an ng-model that way I can use it later, I'll be a happy man.

Comment: Do you have to use a <select> ? I would suggest you just use a div with a label and and a check box. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-can-angularjs-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values

Comment: @jw56578 I would prefer it to be a select box because provData could be insanely large and I don't want to clutter the page.

Comment: you can easily add the same type of behavior yourself. that being having a scrollable space. does this make sense: http://jsfiddle.net/MitulP91/xEy9E/3/

Answer (score 1):

Based on Rashim's blog, this is what I tried in Plunke. 
https://rashimuddin.wordpress.com/2014/07/08/multi-select-drop-down-in-angularjs/

Check this out
http://plnkr.co/edit/y8VOlgeSMOqHjFxoZU1L?p=preview`enter code here`

HTML

```
 <div dropdown-multiselect="" items="FirstItems" on-close="closeAlert(val)" on-Validation="addAlert(validationMsg)" max-Selection="3" selected-items="FirstSelectedItems"></div>
```

Angular directive would be

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('AppCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {

$scope.status = {
  isopen: false
};

$scope.FirstItems = [];

$scope.alerts = [{
  type: 'danger',
  msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.'
}, {
  type: 'success',
  msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.'
}];

$scope.addAlert = function(validationMsg) {
  if ($scope.validateFire === true) {
    $scope.alerts.push({
      msg: validationMsg
    });
  }
  $scope.validateFire = true;
};

$scope.closeAlert = function(val) {
  $scope.alerts = [];
}

for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
  var obj = [];
  obj["Id"] = i;
  obj["Name"] = "Name" + i;
  obj["IsSelected"] = false;
  $scope.FirstItems.push(obj);
}

$scope.FirstSelectedItems = [];

var removeItem = function(items, item) {
  for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    if (item.Id == items[index].Id) {
      item.IsSelected = false;
      items.splice(index, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
};

$scope.removeFirstItem = function(item) {
  removeItem($scope.FirstSelectedItems, item);
};
$scope.removeSecondItem = function(item) {
  removeItem($scope.SecondSelectedItems, item);
};}]);
```

Directive goes like this

app.directive('dropdownMultiselect', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      items: "=",
      selectedItems: "=",
      maxSelection: "=",
      validateFire: "=",
      onValidation: '&',
      onClose: '&'
    },
    template: "" +
      "" +
      "Add " +
      "" +
      "" +
      "" +
      "" +
      "All " +
      "None" +
      "" +
      "
" +
      "" +
      "  " +
      "{{item.Name}}" +
      "" +
      "" +
      "",
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.handleClick = function($event) {
        $event.stopPropagation();
      };
      $scope.status = {
        isopen: false
      };
      $scope.status = {
        isopen: false
      };

```
  $scope.openDropdown = function($event) {
    if ($scope.items !== undefined && $scope.items.length > 0) {

      if ($scope.items.length > $scope.maxSelection)
        $scope.showAll = false;
      else
        $scope.showAll = true;

      for (var index = 0; index < $scope.items.length; index++) {
        $scope.items[index].IsSelected = false;
      }
      if ($scope.selectedItems !== undefined && $scope.selectedItems.length > 0) {
        for (var selectedItemIndex = 0; selectedItemIndex < $scope.selectedItems.length; selectedItemIndex++) {
          for (var itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < $scope.items.length; itemIndex++) {
            if ($scope.selectedItems[selectedItemIndex].Id == $scope.items[itemIndex].Id) {
              $scope.items[itemIndex].IsSelected = true;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.status.isopen = true;
  };

  $scope.selectAll = function($event) {
    $scope.selectedItems = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
      item.IsSelected = true;
      $scope.selectedItems.push(item);
    });
    $event.stopPropagation();
  };
  $scope.deselectAll = function($event) {
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
      item.IsSelected = false;
    });
    $scope.selectedItems = [];
    $event.stopPropagation();
  };
  $scope.selectItem = function(item) {
    if (item.IsSelected === false) {
      for (var index = 0; index < $scope.selectedItems.length; index++) {
        if (item.Id == $scope.selectedItems[index].Id) {
          item.IsSelected = false;
          $scope.selectedItems.splice(index, 1);

          $scope.onClose({
            val: "1"
          });

          break;
        }
      }
    } else {
      if ($scope.selectedItems.length > $scope.maxSelection) {
        item.IsSelected = false;
        $scope.validationMsg = "MAX_REACHED";
        $scope.validateFire = true;
        $scope.onValidation({
          validationMsg: "Max_Reached"
        });
        return;
      }

      $scope.selectedItems.push(item);
    }
  };

  $scope.clickItem = function($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
  };

  $scope.closeDropDown = function() {
    $scope.status.isopen = false;
    $event.stopPropagation();
  };
}
```

};
});`

Comment: Link-only answers are insufficient on stackoverflow.  Links should be included to provided additional information on your answer, not to serve *as* the answer.