# How to stop select element opening when the view loads?

Tags: html, angularjs-directive

I have a multi-selectable select element, but when the multiple attribute is used it loads in an open state.

I want it to appear as a dropdown and only open when I click on it.
(I am using AngularJS ver 1.4.9)

```
  <div class="btn-group">
      <select ng-options="e for e in vm.plannedEmployees track by e" multiple="multiple" ng-model="selectedEmployee" ng-change="vm.employeeSelectClick(selectedEmployee)">
      </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS directive for a multi-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568651/angularjs-directive-for-a-multi-select)

Comment: See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y8stzw6s/1/) -- that's without any AngularJS. Just plain ole HTML. Note how it is in an "open" state. That's how multiple selects have rendered since time immemorial.