# How to Angularize a jQuery control so it will updated after HTML is rendered

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-plugins

I need a multi-select control in my Angular app. I found found a few that work with Angular, but i like the look and options on a control built for jQuery, http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

What is the simplest way to do something like `$('#example-getting-started').multiselect("refresh");` after the data binding is complete on the `select` element?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954605/how-can-i-use-bootstrap-multiselect-dropdown-in-angularjs

Comment: Dang, how did I miss this? Thanks, I'll try it out.